# I'm soliciting questions from others; OK to mention that in the question?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I'm asking some people rather deeper into the industry than Your Humble Servant for questions, in my ongoing quest to get a better handle on [what constitutes "expert questions"](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215/expert-questions-on-writers-se).

At least one of the people I asked sent me back questions to post myself. Do people mind if I note who the question's from? E.g. [here](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/3317).

It feels a little odd and out-of-place ("this question brought to you by..."). OTOH, I would like to give the author credit; also, at least in one question, he makes reference to experience with editors and magazines I simply don't have, and I'd rather not create an exaggerated impression about my experience and writing :P

Comment: It's fine to mention it in the question, but I'm not sure you have to.  The SO blog talked about attracting attention to your community by showing how it can answer the experts' questions for them and illustrated it with an example using Apple.SE, where he didn't include the original twitter asker's handle or name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should note from who the question is. I answered your question with a question to the OP (which is James in this scenario, not you). If you don't provide that information and answer my question with "I don't know, it's not my story." then that would be disturbing at best.

Also, as you have mentioned, writing about "several editors rejected the book" and never have finished one yourself (what I just make up for the sake of the argument) would again be disturbing.

Not to mention James' intellectual property and that we need good questions. (I'm still in favor for that sock puppet account, but so what.)

Answer (score 4):

This is explicitly OK, per the blog:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/

You could mention naturally that you're asking on behalf of someone else, e.g.:

> I was reading the blog of noted author Eljibim Mutakwo and he brought up an interesting point ...